# he had the manager check it vs. he had it checked by the manager

Tags: passive-voice, infinitive-clauses, causatives

*(a) He had it checked by the manager.*

*(b) He had the manager check it.*

Could you please clarify the difference between these sentences, if there is any?

Comment: The latter is more direct/forceful, as the first is in _passive voice_. In fact, the latter phrasing sounds _as if you can tell the manager what to do._

Comment: @BrianHitchcock Both are in the active voice. It is the subordinate complement clause which is in the passive voice in the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all about what do you want to emphasize.

In the first sentence, you emphasize something that had to be ***checked***. In the latter one, you give weight to ***the manager*** who was specially asked to check it.

Comment: @J.R. ah, by the way, *weightage* is Asian English.

Comment: I don't want to repeat this, but Indian English is not Asian English. I'm not even sure if Asian English is a well-defined or established term. Having said that, I agree that *[weightage](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/weightage)* is Indian English. And South Asian English would cover Indian English, as far as I know.

Comment: But we *do* have [English as an Asian Language](http://www.theguardian.com/education/2000/nov/23/tefl.guardianweekly)! @DamkerngT.

Comment: Ah, and [this one](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=weightage) as a supplement  @DamkerngT.

Comment: @MaulikV - I had guessed that _weightage_ might be Indian English, but only a fraction of the readers of this answer might be from India or surrounding countries. I would not have changed that on its own, but since I was making another change anyway, I thought it wouldn't hurt to make the answer more applicable to the global population.